# GenericException : Collection was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

I have searched for this problem and I know it is caused because an array is manipulated while its enumeration. Earlier in my code, I was using :

```
-(BOOL)busy
{
for(DataRequest* request in self.active)
    if(!request.invisible)
        return YES;

return NO;
}
```

and `-(BOOL)busy` is being called very frequently as the data loads from the server. Also in my code I have some lines which adds and removes objects in `self.active`. And because of this I was getting the exception. Then I made a change in the code as:

```
-(BOOL)busy
{
self.tempActive = self.active;
for(DataRequest* request in _tempActive)
    if(!request.invisible)
        return YES;

return NO;
}
```

but I am still getting the same exception. What am I doing wrong, any ideas? This is the only code where `self.tempActive` is used.

The exception I am getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x9ec8f60> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Comment: What s the exception>?

Comment: self.tempActive = self.active is only copying the pointer - therefore you're keeping referring to the same array. I'm not sure what is the problem you are having - but if this is related to accessing directly self.active you should then make a copy of it self.tempActive = [self.active copy]. This way you have a different object which is a copy of the original array. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between classes and stack objects (like ints and things).  Setting something equal to something else does *not* make a copy of it if it is a class.  You need to use `[self.active copy]` instead.